# Parent child relationship - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data where there are parent and child product.

Each parent has got a unique code(P1) and a link code (L1) on their account and each child of the parent has got a seperate code (C12) but they share the same account no.

I want to count the parent and children

Here is a sample dataset

```
create table #Something
(
   Line_no int,
   code varchar(5),
   AccountNo char(5)
)
```

Some sample data

```
INSERT #Something
select 12311, 'P1c', 'Ac115' union all
select 12311, 'L1', 'Ac115' union all
select 123, 'C1', 'Ac115' union all
select 1222, 'C1', 'Ac115' union all
select 1243, 'C1', 'Ac115' union all
select 433, 'P1a', 'Ac111' union all
select 433, 'L1', 'Ac111' union all
select 4331, 'C1', 'Ac111' union all
select 543, 'C1', 'Ac222' union all
select 544, 'C1', 'Ac222' union all
select 4322, 'P1b', 'Ac222' union all
select 4322, 'L1', 'Ac222' union all

select 8766,'P1d' , 'Ab111' union all
select 8766,'L1' , 'Ab111' union all
select 8767,'C1', 'Ab111' union all
select 8789,'P1d', 'Ab119' union all
select 8766,'L1', 'Ab119' union all
select 876654,'C1', 'Ab119' union all
select 876655,'C1', 'Ab119' union all
select 876698,'P1a', 'Ab117' union all
select 876698,'L1', 'Ab117' union all
select 987,'C1', 'Ab117' union all
select 555444,'P1d','Xcv' union all
select 555444,'L1','Xcv' union all
select 6754,'C1','Xcv'

SELECT * from #Something

drop table #Something
```

Desired output is:

```
[Parent code] [Parent line Count] [Child line Count]    
  P1c                1                   3
  P1a                2                   2
  P1b                1                   2
  P1d                3                   4
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you tell that `P..` is parent and `C..` is a child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird schema, but this query will give you what you want:

```
with cte as (
    select
        max(case when code like 'P%' then code end) as [Parent code],
        count(case when code like 'P%' then code end) as [Parent line Count],
        count(case when code like 'C%' then code end) as [Child line Count]
    from Something
    group by AccountNo
)
select
    [Parent code],
    sum([Parent line Count]) as [Parent line Count],
    sum([Child line Count]) as [Child line Count]
from cte
group by [Parent code]
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5260fd/2)</kbd>**

If you don't like common table expressions, you can use subquery:

```
select
    [Parent code],
    sum([Parent line Count]) as [Parent line Count],
    sum([Child line Count]) as [Child line Count]
from (
    select
        max(case when code like 'P%' then code end) as [Parent code],
        count(case when code like 'P%' then code end) as [Parent line Count],
        count(case when code like 'C%' then code end) as [Child line Count]
    from Something
    group by AccountNo
) as A
group by [Parent code]
```